# Find element with at least $\frac{n}{2}$ repeats in an array

Tags: algorithms, divide-and-conquer

I saw this question on my college "Design of Algorithms" exam but I could not solve it:

Given an array $A[1..n]$ of integers. find an element which is repeated at least $\frac{n}{2}$ times using **Divide and Conquer** algorithm in $O(n\log{n})$ if such element exists.

Correctness of the algorithm must be proven.

---

I wonder if there's any answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sorting the array, you could use the following divide-and-conquer algorithm. For simplicity, I will suppose that one searches an element that appears strictly more than $\frac{n}{2}$ times, but it could also be done with the equality case.

```
Algorithm: Majority(A)
Input: array A[1...n]
Output: element x that appears > n/2 times if it exists, or false otherwise

If n = 1: 
   return A[1]
Else:
   x1 := Majority(A[1...n/2])
   x2 := Majority(A[n/2+1...n])
   If x1 ≠ false and x1 appears > n/2 times in A:
      return x1
   If x2 ≠ false and x2 appears > n/2 times in A:
      return x2
   return false
```

The algorithm is correct, because if $x$ appears $>\frac{n}{2}$ times in $A$, then $x$ appears $>\frac{n}{4}$ times in at least one half of $A$.

The time complexity $C(n)$ verifies:

- $C(1) = \mathcal{O}(1)$;
- $C(n)$ is the sum of:

  - $2C(n/2)$: both recursive calls to `Majority`;
  - $\mathcal{O}(n)$: verification of $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $A$

So $C(n) = 2C(n/2) + \mathcal{O}(n) = \mathcal{O}(n\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest but not the optimal way to solve your problem.

Since you can use $O(n\log{n})$ time and your algorithm needs to use Divide and Conquer, you can solve the problem by:

```
1. Use Merge Sort to sort the array A     
2. For i = 1...n/2                        
3.    If A[i] == A[n/2 + i] return A[i]
```

The first step works in $O(n\log{n})$ which is the worst case complexity for merge sort and the for loop works in $O(n)$ (i.e., $\frac{n}{2}$ comparisons) in the worst case, so the overall complexity is $O(n\log{n})$. Furthermore, if $A[i] == A[\frac{n}{2} + i]$, it is guaranteed that the elements in between are also equal to $A[i]$, because the array is sorted. If no such element has been found by the midpoint of the array, $A[\frac{n}{2}]$, no such number exists in the array since any other element appears at most $\frac{n}{2} - 1$ times.

Comment: I might call Quicksort "Divide and Conquer" as well, but not "Heapsort".

Comment: @gnasher729 I don't mention Quicksort becasue worst case complexity would be $O(n^2)$. The question mentions an exam and I assumed worst case complexity was implied since it wasn't specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Say I have 201 integers. You need to find one that occurs at least 101 times. Split the integers into 100 and 101 integers. To occur 101 times in total, your integer must occur 51 times in one of the two halves.

Now you turn this into an algorithm.